# Refactor problem, tring to inject function but fail

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

I'm using react to create a **test component**, which is used in **ContainerA** and **ContainerB**.

**test component**:

```
renderTitle(){

    let mode = this.modeType[this.state.mode];

    switch (mode){
        case 'A':
            title =
                <div onClick={this.switchMode.bind(this,'next')}>
                    <div>A</div>
                </div>;
            break;
        case 'B':
            title =
                <div onClick={this.switchMode.bind(this,'next')}>
                    <div>B</div>
                </div>;
            break;
        case 'C':
            title =
                <div onClick={this.switchMode.bind(this,'next')}>
                    <div>C</div>
                </div>;
            break;
        case 'D':
            title =
                <div>
                    <div>D</div>
                </div>;
            break;
    }

    return(
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-around">
            {title}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I found that mode A,B,C will only used in **ContainerA** and mode D will only used in **ContainerB**.

So I tried to refactor **test component** into following:

```
renderTitle(){

    let mode = this.modeType[this.state.mode];

    let title = this.props.setTitle(mode);

    return(
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-around">
            {title}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And change container like following:

**ContainerA**

```
export class ContainerA extends Component{

    setTitle(mode){

        switch (mode){
            case 'A':
                title =
                    <div onClick={this.switchMode.bind(this,'next')}>
                        <div>A</div>
                    </div>;
                break;
            case 'B':
                title =
                    <div onClick={this.switchMode.bind(this,'next')}>
                        <div>B</div>
                    </div>;
                break;
            case 'C':
                title =
                    <div onClick={this.switchMode.bind(this,'next')}>
                        <div>C</div>
                    </div>;
                break;
        }

        return title
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div >
                <Test setTitle={this.setTitle.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**ContainerB**

```
export class ContainerA extends Component{

    setTitle(mode){

        let test=    
            <div>
                <div>D</div>
            </div>;


        return title
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div >
                <Test setTitle={this.setTitle.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But **switchMode()** is inside the **test component**, so how to set the onClick event handler?

Answer (score 0):

A solution I use to call a function in a parent component, from an event that is handled inside a child component, is the following.

Parent Class

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    actualEvent(data) {
        // do something here
    }
    render() {
        return <Child onClick={this.actualEvent.bind(this)}/>
    }
}
```

Child Class

```
class Child extends React.Component {

    onClick(evt) {
        if (this.props.onClick)
            this.props.onClick(/* some data if required */);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>whatever</div>
        )
    }
}
```

basically, the idea is in the child component where the actual event happens, you call a function that you apply as a property from the parent.